# SQL Syntax Error in QGIS near 'DELETE'

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql

I can't understand what is wrong in my syntax, or if this is specifically an issue with QGIS but I am hoping someone can explain why I am still receiving a syntax error for this.

I am trying to delete rows based on certain words found in social media posts as they do not apply to my research focus, namely dog-walking.

Here is my SQL query;

```
DELETE FROM dog_posts_insta
WHERE ((text LIKE '%brew%') OR (text LIKE '%beer%'));
```

For which I continuously receive a syntax error for `near "DELETE"`

What am I missing?

My version of QGIS: 3.4 Madeira
Here is a sample of my table as requested:
[image: qgis_table]

Comment: Have you seen this article [DELETE FROM … reporting syntax error at or near “.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985083/delete-from-reporting-syntax-error-at-or-near)? By the way can you show how does your table look like?

Comment: I looked at that article before I posted, yes, unfortunately, doesn't seem to be applicable in my situation as my table name is not a reserved word, nor am I deleting over a join.

Comment: Strange, I cannot see any problems with it. Try to run it with "select *" in stead of  "delete" -

Comment: Are you absolute sure there is nothing before "DELETE" - by some string concatenation of some kind? Where are you running this query?

Comment: Running SELECT * works well without any problems. I have closed QGIS and restarted the program, re-written the query entirely and still receive the same error at "delete." I am running this in the SQL window of DB Manager of QGIS on a virtual layer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about a qgis *virtual layer* i fear **DELETE** queries aren't allowed ...

*(i think they can only be seen as 'views')*

ps : or ... do u mean u're running that query using **postgre/postgis** ?

Comment: Damn it is in a virtual layer, yes. Did not that would be a factor. Any advice for removing from a virtual layer?

Comment: @redleesy You have to rewrite your virtual-layer-query so you exclude your unwanted text.  select ..... where '%text NOT like 'argument1%', etc

Comment: ok, i see! thank you for the help.